# Stop GNU make from compiling by default

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I just want to use GNU make to compress some files.
So I wrote the Makefile as follows:

```
lib.tar.lzma: $(shell find ~/lib -name "*")
    rm -f lib.tar.lzma
    tar -cavf lib.tar.lzma -C ~/ lib/
```

However, after I run make, it automatically compile the c++ source code in that directory.

How can I stop it from compiling them? I just want to compress them.

***Update:***

I got the following error:

```
<builtin>: recipe for target '/home/xxx/lib/app' failed
```

It seems a built-in recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(We don't know your *entire* `Makefile` and your *full* file tree, so this is only a guess; I assume that you have shown us a *fragment* of your much bigger `Makefile`)

> However, after I run make, it automatically compile the c++ source code in that directory.

This is probably happening because your  `$(shell find ~/lib -name "*")` is expanded to something containing your object files. Since they are in your *dependencies* their source file is recompiled if it is newer. BTW you might want to use instead `$(shell cd .. ; find lib -name "*")` or if `lib` has no subdirectory even `$(wildcard ../lib/*)`

You probably don't need any dependency for that `lib.tar.lzma` target, so just have:

```
lib.tar.lzma: 
     rm -f lib.tar.lzma
     tar -cavf lib.tar.lzma -C ~/ lib/
```

<sup>BTW, that `-C ~/` perhaps should be `-C $$HOME` since `make` use `/bin/sh` to run commands, and that POSIX shell don't know about `~` ; perhaps a `-C ..` might be better ...</sup>

Perhaps you might write some shell script `make-backup.sh` to do a more clever `tar` and you would then code

```
lib.tar.lzma: make-backup.sh
      ./make-backup.sh $@
```

However, perhaps you *do* have dependencies (e.g. if you need to archive some *generated* files). Then you need to list them explicitly and wisely (you certainly don't want to depend on all the files; perhaps only the source ones). Also, you might not need to archive any object files `*.o`, if you have some (but YMMV).

I recommend using `make --trace` or [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x` to debug your Makefile.

BTW, having a `Makefile` *only* for a backup is useless; write a shell script instead.

I also strongly recommend using some version control system (like [git](http://git-scm.com/)) if you don't use any. Notice that `git` has an `archive` subcommand which might be a more clever backup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I do need to have dependencies to update the archive. BTW, I got the following error:     <builtin>: recipe for target '/home/xxx/lib/app' failed

Comment: Actually, there are implicit rules, and I should add a line .SUFFIXES to disable them.